# PyCharm [Intellij] auto-import from Binary Skeletons instead of standard python library

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, python-3.10

I'm trying to import Decimal from `decimal` but when I try and do this using Intellij it just says I can import from `_decimal` instead which is in the Binary Skeletons.

I'm using Poetry and Python 3.10, and it's almost certainly something wrong with my setup, I just can't work out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Known issue

[YouTrack: Cannot import `Decimal` with a quick-fix](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-58464/Cannot-import-Decimal-with-a-quick-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you may expect but...

## Use bare import

```py
import decimal

decimal.Decimal
```

I stopped relying on Pycharm for auto import mainly because of this. This issue exist since years. I don't use Poetry.

Same issue with, for example, `Sequence`.

[image: Sequence import with pycharm]

Here (python 3.11 used), `Sequence` is deprecated but accessible in `typing` and located in `collections.abc`, but Pycharm keep trying to import it from `typing`.

Comment: Unfortunately I think a different problem as mine seems to be related to it picking up the Decimal from the Binary Skeleton instead of Python 3.10 and I believe yours is that Sequence appears deprecated in `typing` still. :(

Comment: Hum, my pycharm import it from decimal. What version of pycharm do you use?

Comment: I just upgraded as  your other comment and it's still happening. I'm going to investigate a bit more tonight I have another laptop which doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Do you use a virtual env?

Comment: yeah, with poetry, inside the project .venv.

Comment: I'm using intellij, and I've set up the project structure to use a poetry virtual environment

Comment: Try with venv? I don't know it this can make a diff, but if it change something, it will give us some information. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I did a bunch of tries for things and couldn't find anything.
Reinstalled Intellij and still no luck. I think it has to do with my Python installation, so that's my next job :\

Comment: @HenryB have you open a ticket to jetbrain issue tracker?

Comment: Yeah in fact it is a known issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-58464/Cannot-import-Decimal-with-a-quick-fix

Comment: Then too bad ^^